# Weights are not able to be set correctly on the mesh and armature

Tags: armature, weight-painting

The Character mesh and armature are working fine together but the clothes on top are not able to be set correctly with weights: [image]

Attachment of Blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yMB15Y_RiNTub1-sLhGLyI_Usc8_074m/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What methods are you using to set the weights?

Comment: your rest pose should be a T pose (arms spread horizontally) with both the 2 meshes (vest and character) following the same pose. I would also join the vest and the character. Once done you can parent with automatic weight